# Equivalent of Ruby Enumerable.collect that returns an Enumerable?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

In this code, I create an array of strings "1" to "10000":

```
array_of_strings = (1..10000).collect {|i| String(i)}
```

Does the Ruby Core API provide a way to get an enumerable object that lets me enumerate over the same list, generating the string values on demand, rather than generating an array of the strings?

Here's a further example which hopefully clarifies what I am trying to do:

```
def find_me_an_awesome_username
  awesome_names = (1..1000000).xform {|i| "hacker_" + String(i) }
  awesome_names.find {|n| not stackoverflow.userexists(n) }
end
```

Where `xform` is the method I am looking for.
awesome_names is an Enumerable, so `xform` isn't creating a 1 million element array of strings, but just generating and returning strings of the form "hacker_[N]" on demand.

By the way, here's what it might look like in C#:

```
var awesomeNames = from i in Range(1, 1000000) select "hacker_" + i;
var name = awesomeNames.First((n) => !stackoverflow.UserExists(n));
```

**(One Solution)**

Here is an extension to Enumerator that adds an xform method. It returns another enumerator which iterates over the values of the original enumerator, with a transform applied to it.

```
class Enumerator
  def xform(&block)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      self.each do |val|
        yielder.yield block.call(val)
      end
    end
  end
end

# this prints out even numbers from 2 to 10:
(1..10).each.xform {|i| i*2}.each {|i| puts i}
```

Comment: ...should read '2 to 20'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby 2.0 introduced [`Enumerable#lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy) which allows one to chain `map`, `select`, etc..., and only generate the final results at the end with `to_a`, `first`, etc... You can use it in any Ruby version with `require 'backports/2.0.0/enumerable/lazy'`.

```
require 'backports/2.0.0/enumerable/lazy'
names = (1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.map{|i| "hacker_" + String(i) }
names.first # => 'hacker_1'
```

Otherwise, you can use `Enumerator.new { with_a_block }`. It's new in Ruby 1.9, so `require 'backports/1.9.1/enumerator/new'` if you need it in Ruby 1.8.x.

As per your example, the following will not create an intermediate array and will only construct the needed strings:

```
require 'backports/1.9.1/enumerator/new'

def find_me_an_awesome_username
  awesome_names = Enumerator.new do |y|
    (1..1000000).each {|i| y.yield "hacker_" + String(i) }
  end
  awesome_names.find {|n| not stackoverflow.userexists(n) }
end
```

You can even replace the 100000 by 1.0/0 (i.e. Infinity), if you want.

To answer your comment, if you are always mapping your values one to one, you could have something like:

```
module Enumerable
  def lazy_each
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      each do |value|
        yielder.yield(yield value)
      end
    end
  end
end

awesome_names = (1..100000).lazy_each{|i| "hacker_#{i}"}
```

Comment: @marc, this looks like it! Do you know how I might turn this pattern into a more concise re-usable method taking an 'enumerable thing', and a 'transformer function'?

In this example, the 'transformer function' would be `{|i| "hacker_" + String(i) }`, and the 'enumerable thing' would be `(1..100000)` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks very much. I updated my question with a possible implementation that I worked out from your answer, and also from reading the link that @Telemachus posted, before I noticed *your* update :) Again, thanks!

Comment: @mackenir: The Enumerable transform function is `map`. You should just be able to change `each` to `map` and keep the algorithm otherwise unchanged.

Comment: @Chuck Enumerable#map is a synonym for Enumerable#collect so it returns an array rather than an Enumerator.

Comment: @mackenir: Actually, I misread. How is the method given *not* what you're asking for? It takes a transformer function and gives an enumerator that yields the result of applying that transformation.

Comment: @Chuck - by 'the method given' do you mean Enumerable#map? It isn't what I'm after, as it returns an array.

Comment: @mackenir: By "the method given," I mean Marc-Andre's `lazy_each` in this answer. It takes a block and returns an enumerator that yields the results of calling the block on each item in the collection.

Comment: Uh... you've lost me @Chuck. Where did I say otherwise?

Comment: Upcoming in 1.8.8 ... indefinitely upcoming? :)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Indeed. Edited, and updated with upcoming `lazy`

Comment: Updated answer now that 2.0.0 and `lazy` are out

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an Enumerator object, but not exactly.

That is, an Enumerator object is an object that you can use to call `next` on demand (rather than `each` which does the whole loop). (Many people use the language of internal versus external iterators: `each` is internal, and an Enumerator is external. You drive it.)

Here's how an enumerator might look:

```
awesome_names = Enumerator.new do |y|
  number = 1
  loop do
    y.yield number
    number += 1
  end
end

puts awesome_names.next
puts awesome_names.next
puts awesome_names.next
puts awesome_names.next
```

Here's a link, to more discussion of how you might use Enumerators lazily in Ruby: http://www.michaelharrison.ws/weblog/?p=163

There's also a section on this in the Pickaxe book (*Programming Ruby* by Dave Thomas).

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm. Find definitely stops enumerating when it findsa matching element. You can confirm this by running find on a very large range, with the predicate 'false' and 'true' the latter returns instantly. If both were enumerating everything they'd both return in the same time.

Re: enumeration with next, I'm trying to find the 'enumerable transformer' facility in order to write more terse, declarative code, and manually enumerating wont really achieve that.

Maybe the answer is to just implement it.

Comment: With all the CRs removed that's less comprehensible. What I mean is, (1..1000000000000000000).find {|i|true} is quick, and (1..1000000000000000000).find {|i|false} is slow. Meaning find just enumerates until it 'finds'.

Comment: Useful link - I think I understand it, and it helped answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
class T < Range
  def each
    super { |i| yield String(i) }
  end
end

T.new(1,3).each { |s| p s }
$ ruby rsc.rb
"1"
"2"
"3"
```

The next thing to do is to return an Enumerator when called without a block...

Answer (score 0):

lists have an each method:

```
(1..100000).each
```

Comment: ... okay, now you start searching about Ruby iteration.

Comment: But your code just iterates over the integer range. It doesn't generate a new enumerable of strings. Please try and put yourself in my idiot shoes :).

Comment: `(1..100000).each { |j| i = j.to_s ; do_something j }` or did you want to do something different?

Comment: @anshul yes, I want to do something a little different from that. I'd like to separate the code that generates the enumerable from the code that works with the enumerable values. TBH it's not the only way to do it, but would make the code cleaner (in my opinion of course). Thanks.

Comment: @mackenir, you should probably just expose an `each` method that takes a bock and delegates to `Range#each` as suggested. Keep enumerable magic internal to the implementation.

Comment: @molf I don't think working with Enumerator objects directly is that magical, in fact it's pretty useful.